AndroidStudio: error: Unsupported Java. Your build is currently configured to use Java 22.0.1 and Gradle 7.6
gradle-wrapper.properties is:
distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.6-bin.zip
the error message is:
Unsupported Java.
Your build is currently configured to use Java 22.0.1 and Gradle 7.6.
Possible solution:

Open Gradle wrapper settings, change distributionUrl property to use compatible Gradle version and reload the project

how to correct this error?
I already try another versions like 8.x

You need to use Gradle 8.8 for it to be compatible with Java 22
If that doesn't work, please downgrade your Java version
See the compatibility matrix here

Unsupported Java.
Your build is currently configured to use Java 22.0.1 and Gradle 8.8.
Possible solution:

Open Gradle wrapper settings, change distributionUrl property to use compatible Gradle version and reload the project


Try downgrading your Java version, maybe

Thank you, i downgrade the JDK to 17, and Thank you, now it works.

Could you mark the answer as accepted so that it helps others? There's a small ticket on the left side of the answer
